# How to change text based on textarea length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I added the following code, and I am getting the text to update, but *only* when clicking outside of the textarea.

```
$('.form__input-el').change(function() {
    $('.form__character-indicator').text($('.form__input-el').val().length);
})
```

Why is this happening and how can I make it update without clicking outside of the textarea?

Comment: can you add your html plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you you can use keyup if you want to get change the output immediately

```js
$('.form__input-el').keyup(function() {
    $('.form__character-indicator').text($('.form__input-el').val().length);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form__input-el"></textarea>
<div class="form__character-indicator"></div>
```

Comment: You should add an event handler to `.mouseup()` as well since right-clicking and pasting doesn't modify the count.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `input` instead of `change` this will trigger everytime the user inputs something.

Answer (score 1):

according to jQuery docs: `For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus`

This is why your event appears only on leaving the textareas focus.

https://api.jquery.com/change/

a complete list of the events can be found here:

https://api.jquery.com/category/events/

so you need to use another event, maybe like:

https://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Answer (score 1):

Use a `keyup` event to update your character count while the user is typing

Try something like this

```
$('.textarea').on('keyup', function() {

  var newCount = $(this).val().length

 $('.count').html(newCount)

})
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3nncz47d/1/)

Comment: `Why is this happening and how can I make it update without clicking outside of the textarea?`